# check from in side a web part code if the user have a permission to Certain moss page

Tags: sharepoint

hello my goal is to check 
from in side a web part code if the user have a permission to  Certain moss page.
i am using sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page it is item of DocLib named Pages. You can see it permissions. [For example](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/03/sharepoint-can-user-addeditview-this.html)